# c execvp piped ls to grep

Tags: c, grep, pipe

I want to execute the "ls" command, and pipe the result to the "wc" command with the flag "-l" which now works perfectly fine now. Furthermore I wanted to do a grep command in between the two with the parameter "-v lab".

Now I do get the following error in my shell:

```
grep: invalid option -- ' '
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Here is my current code that I'm working with.

```
/* Execute ls | grep -v lab | wc -l */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static void xpipe(int *fd)
{
   if (pipe(fd) == -1)
   {
      err(1, "pipe error");
   }
}
static void xdup2(int a, int b)
{
   if (dup2(a, b) == -1)
   {
      err(1, "dup2 error");
   }
}
static void xclose(int fd)
{
   if (close(fd) == -1)
   {
      err(1, "close error");
   }
}

static void execute(int *fd, char **cmd, int w)
{
   switch (fork())
   {
   case -1:
      err(EXIT_FAILURE, "fork failed");
   case 0:
      xdup2(fd[w], w);
      xclose(fd[0]);
      xclose(fd[1]);
      execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
      perror("execvp failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

I think the main problem is in here at the execute grep function but I don't see any mistake in my *grep[] array.

```
int main(void)
{
   int rv = EXIT_SUCCESS;
   char *ls[] = {"ls", NULL};
   char *grep[] = {"grep", "-v lab", NULL};
   char *wordcount[] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};
   int fd[2];
   xpipe(fd);
   execute(fd, ls, 1);
   execute(fd, grep, 1);
   execute(fd, wordcount, 0);
   xclose(fd[0]);
   xclose(fd[1]);

   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   {
      int status;
      wait(&status);
      if (!WIFEXITED(status) || WEXITSTATUS(status))
      {
         rv = EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }
   return rv;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious about the grep command or in my code?

Comment: The arguments `"-v"` and `"lab"` need to be two separate strings.

Comment: I'm flabbergasted that I could not find a better duplicate for this common FAQ. If you understand Python or Javascript it's probably easy to find a near-duplicate about similar errors in those languages.

Comment: If you expect to execute `ls | grep | wc`, you would expect to need 2 pipes.  But you only call `xpipe` once.